# Is this right Script?

Tags: vbscript, scripting, windows-server-2003, group-policy

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\my_server_name\my_printer_name"
```

hello all,

i used the script written above in a windows server 2003 (group policy management) running in a virtual machine then i used the command "gpupdate /force", but when i go to the client machine nothing happend

Comment: Your script is syntactically correct, so if it's not working, the problem lies someplace else. The client machine is connected to the server running in the virtual machine? What are you *expecting* to happen on the client machine?

Comment: @Cody Gray: hello i created about 15 policies all work except this the network 100% working between my sever and my client computer (all run in virtual environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, what was wrong is I should put the script in Default logon folder in the server